# Meaning of "exclusive+ to, of, in" in the given scenarios

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions

1. Both of these albums are EXCLUSIVE to this Pledge.
2. They rapidly became exclusive of others. Any such prices are exclusive of tax.
3. We are always exclusive in quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exclusive** always has meaning related to things being excluded. The different prepositions change what is being excluded from where.

If something is **exclusive to** something else, it means that that is the only way to get/see/eat/heat/whatever it.

> Use of this room is exclusive to members of the club.

This means that everyone who is not a member of the club is *excluded* from using the room.

If something is **exclusive of** something else, it means that it excludes it. It is not included.

> Prices exclusive of tax.

Tax has not been included in the stated price.

> They agreed that their relationship should be exclusive.

Neither of them will be in such a relationship with anyone else - there's an implied "of others".

"**Exclusive in**" is a different beast. It appears to relate to the idea of "exclusive" as an adjective without an argument - where the *of* and *to* forms have an arguments. A choice might be exclusive, meaning you can only choose one of the options. A list might be exclusive, which I think is the same as being exhaustive - anything not on the list isn't included. Where a list isn't exhaustive, you might head it with "including but not limited to". However, I don't think that's what's happening here.

Something can be described as exclusive to suggest that it is of such quality, or so excellent in some characteristic, that you would expect it to be restricted in availability. Exclusive clubs try to project the idea that you want to be a member because their stuff is just so good. Products are sold as "exclusive to [shopname]" in an attempt to show they are good (even though that doesn't logically follow). Thus, exclusive has grown to include a meaning of excellence, rather than just its literal meaning.